# Find Gaps Between date ranges

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime

I need your help. I'm trying to figure out how I can get find Gaps between EndDate and the next StartDate. If there is a Gap I need to return the values where the gap is. Can you please help me?

I have a list with StartDate and Enddate.
Example:

1. Startdate: 2/01/2021 Enddate: 2/10/2021
2. Startdate: 2/11/2021 **Enddate: 2/15/2021**
3. **Startdate: 2/20/2021** Enddate: 2/25/2021

Between 1 and 2 is no Gap. Between 2 (Enddate) and 3 (Stardate) is a Gap and needs to return a result like this: **Gap found between 2/16/2021 and 2/19/2021.**

I already tried this one but it didn't work out for me well, may someone of you can help me here?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<DateRanges> DateRanges = new List<DateRanges>();
        DateRanges.Add(new DateRanges() { StartDate = new DateTime(2021, 01, 01), EndDate = new DateTime(2021, 01, 31) });
        DateRanges.Add(new DateRanges() { StartDate = new DateTime(2021, 02, 10), EndDate = new DateTime(2021, 02, 25) });

        var missing = DateRangeEnumerable.GetDates(DateRanges);
        var ranges = missing.GetRanges();
    }


public class DateRanges
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    //public DateRanges(DateTime Start, DateTime End)
    //{
    //    StartDate = Start;
    //    EndDate = End;
    //}
}


public static class DateRangeEnumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDates(this IEnumerable<DateRanges> source)
    {
        var sortedSource = source.OrderBy(r => r.StartDate);

        foreach (var range in sortedSource)
        {
            var d = range.StartDate;
            while (d < range.EndDate)
            {
                yield return d;
                d = d.AddDays(1);
            }
        }
    }
    public static IEnumerable<DateRanges> GetRanges(this IEnumerable<DateTime> source)
    {
        var sortedSource = source.OrderBy(d => d);
        var enumerator = sortedSource.GetEnumerator();

        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        DateTime from = enumerator.Current;
        DateTime prev = from;

        while (true)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (enumerator.Current == prev.AddDays(1))
                        prev = enumerator.Current;
                    else
                        break;
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return new DateRanges() { StartDate = from, EndDate = prev.AddDays(1) };
                    yield break;
                }

            }

            yield return new DateRanges() { StartDate = from, EndDate = prev.AddDays(1) };

            from = enumerator.Current;
            prev = enumerator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you convert it to dates? I would iterate through the ranges, remembering the previous end date, and compare it to the current start date. If its not equal then create a new "missing range", starting from previous end date + 1 and ending on current start date -1

Comment: If you want to sort the ranges use a custom comparer with `OrderBy` or `List<T>.Sort`, don't expand the range.  Doing so *lose* the range information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Exmaple**

```
var dateRanges = new List<DateRanges>
{
   new() {StartDate = new DateTime(2021, 2, 01), EndDate = new DateTime(2021, 2, 10)},
   new() {StartDate = new DateTime(2021, 02, 11), EndDate = new DateTime(2021, 02, 15)},
   new() {StartDate = new DateTime(2021, 02, 20), EndDate = new DateTime(2021, 02, 25)}
};

var end = dateRanges.First().EndDate;
foreach (var range in dateRanges.Skip(1))
{
   if(end.AddDays(1) <  range.StartDate )
      Console.WriteLine($"{end.AddDays(1):d} - {range.StartDate.AddDays(-1):d}");
   end = range.EndDate;
}
```

**Output**

```
16/02/2021 - 19/02/2021
```

<sub>***Disclaimer** : This contains no error checking, no sorting, nothing implied from your code, and assumes that dates have no time value. It merely just replicates your description*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**What about using a linked list ?**

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ranges = new List<DateRange>();

            ranges.Add(
                new DateRange
                {
                    StartDate = new DateTime(2021, 01, 01),
                    EndDate = new DateTime(2021, 01, 31)
                }
            );

            ranges.Add(
                new DateRange
                {
                    StartDate = new DateTime(2021, 02, 10),
                    EndDate = new DateTime(2021, 02, 25)
                }
            );

            var list = new LinkedList<DateRange>(ranges);

            var gaps = new List<LinkedListNode<DateRange>>();

            var current = list.First;

            while (current != null)
            {
                var next = current.Next;

                if (next != null && next.Value.StartDate > current.Value.EndDate)
                    gaps.Add(current);

                current = next;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Gaps found:");

            foreach (var gap in gaps)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Date Range 1:");
                Console.WriteLine(gap.Value);
                Console.WriteLine("Date Range 2:");
                Console.WriteLine(gap.Next!.Value);
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Gap length in minutes: {(gap.Next.Value.StartDate - gap.Value.EndDate).TotalMinutes}");
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");
            }
        }
    }

    public class DateRange
    {
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{nameof(StartDate)}: {StartDate}, {nameof(EndDate)}: {EndDate}";
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Gaps found:
---------------------------
Date Range 1:
StartDate: 1/1/2021 12:00:00 AM, EndDate: 1/31/2021 12:00:00 AM
Date Range 2:
StartDate: 2/10/2021 12:00:00 AM, EndDate: 2/25/2021 12:00:00 AM
Gap length in minutes: 14400
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can enumerate the gaps like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<DateRanges> Gaps(IEnumerable<DateRanges> dates) {
  var source = dates
    .OrderBy(range => range.StartDate); 

  DateTime last = DateTime.MinValue;
  bool first = true;

  foreach (var range in source) {
    if (!first && range.StartDate.AddDays(1) > last)
      yield return new DateRanges() {
        StartDate = last.AddDays(1), 
        EndDate = range.StartDate.AddDays(-1)) 
     }; 

    // In case of overlapping periods we have to pick the latest date         
    last = first || range.EndDate > last
      ? range.EndDate 
      : last;

    first = false; 
  }
}
```

If you want to print them all you have to do is to loop:

```
foreach (var gap in Gaps(dateRanges))
  Console.WriteLine($"Gap found between {gap.StartDate} and {gap.EndDate}");
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you. 
But this line "yield return (last.AddDays(1), range.StartDate.AddDays(-1));" does not work. Because it's trying to return DateTime and not DateRanges.

Comment: @Ronak: thank you! I've edited the answer - constructor call added.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use a generic extension method that returns subsequent item-pairs:

```
    public static IEnumerable<(T Previous, T Next)> PreviousAndNext<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self)
    {
        using (var iter = self.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!iter.MoveNext())
                yield break;
            var previous = iter.Current;
            while (iter.MoveNext())
            {
                var next = iter.Current;
                yield return (previous, next);
                previous = next;
            }
        }
    }
```

This allow for a very compact linq query

```
DateRanges.PreviousAndNext()
            .Where(p => p.Previous.EndDate.AddDays(1) < p.Next.StartDate)
            .Select(p => (p.Previous.EndDate, p.Next.StartDate));
```